# How to translate 'leader' and 'follower' in partner dance context?

Tags: translation

I build a website about dancing events.

By example, the swing dance require a couple of partner. One of them is 'the leader' (he/she lead the dance) and and the other is 'the follower' (he/she follows the leader).

Given this context, how can I translate 'follower' and 'leader' in Esperanto ?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi havas plurajn eblojn, iel dependas de kiel estra, pela, estas la ago, kaj tio povus dependi de la dancado: `konduki`, `estri`, `gvidi` ...

Mi uzus `gvidanto`/ `gvidato`. `Gvid/i` estas la plej milda kaj iel interkonsenta, el tiuj tri radikoj, do ĝi taŭgas por para danco.

En la Proverbaro [aperas konduki](http://www.robkeetlaer.nl/esperanto/proverbaro/proverbo_001150.htm):

```
Konduki la dancon
```

do `kondukanto` / `kondukato` ankaŭ estus bona traduko.

Ĉiuokaze, elekinte la agan radikon, kunmeto kun `-anto` / `-ato` nomos ambaŭ rolojn.

Answer (score 3):

I have given dance workshops (including swing dances) at Esperanto gatherings before. I use "gvidanto" and "sekvanto" for leader and follower, and I met a few people who use the same terms. I don't think I've ever heard other terms for partner dance roles in Esperanto - not counting when they call it "viro" and "virino", of course.

Naturally the corresponding verbs are "gvidi" and "sekvi", and for switching I'd use "interŝanĝi (rolojn)".

Let me know if there are any other swing dance terms you need to translate. I'd be happy to help. :)